# How to persist input values between different HTML forms?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

My HTML script

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
         <H3> Test </H3>
        <FORM ACTION=test.pl METHOD=POST>
            <p>Please Enter Your Name: </p>
            <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="name">  
            <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT>
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

My Perl script:

```
use CGI;
my $q = CGI->new;
my $m = $q-> param("name");
print "<html>";
print "<body>";
print "<head><title>form test</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "<form method=POST action=test.pl>";
print "<p>First value: </p> <input type = text name = fst>";
print "<p>Second value: </p> <input type = text name = scd>";
print "<input type = submit>";
print "</form>";
my $fname = $q->param("fst");
my $fname2 = $q->param("scd");
my $tot = $fname+$fname2;
print "<h2> hi $m your total value is: $tot</h2>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

After entering a name and submitting the form, the Perl CGI script displays:

```
hi /name/ your total value is:
```

Entering the inputs and submitting this form works successfully but the name isn't displayed, only:

```
hi your total value is: /value/
```

How can I display the name each time the second form is submitted?

Comment: Look into [`CGI::Session`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session) for persisting a value across multiple cgi pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a [hidden input](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/hidden) to the second form with the `name` attribute the same as in the first form:

```
print "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='$m' />";
```

The hidden input won't be displayed to the user but will be submitted along with the other form fields.